# Java get Attributes with DOM Reader

Tags: java, xml

Hey I'd like to get attributes of a Feed.

This is my actual code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(this.getUrlStream());
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                System.out.println("Node name: " + node.getNodeName());
                Element element1 = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("title; " + element1.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
                Element element = (Element) node;
                if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {


                    this.title = element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();




                    System.out.println("description" + element.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());

                    String attribute = element.getAttribute("src");
                    System.out.println(attribute);
                }

            }


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The following part of the code above should find the attribute: "url":

```
String attribute = element.getAttribute("src");
                    System.out.println(attribute);
```

Sysout: Nothing

The Rss-Feed: https://www.spiegel.de/politik/index.rss

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As of this writing, none of the `<item>` elements have a `url` attribute or child, but they have a `<link>` child.  The initial `<image>` element has a `<url>` child;  some of the items have an `<enclosure>` which has a `url` attribute.  Did you mean to print any of those?

Comment: @VGR I'd like to print the url attribute inside the enclosure. Which inside a the item tag.

Comment: You seem to know how to use `element.getElementsByTagName`, so why not use it to get the child `<enclosure>` element, and check that element’s `url` attribute?  Remember that the returned NodeList will have a length of zero if the item doesn’t have an `<enclosure>` child.

Comment: like that? 

nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("enclosure");

            for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Element element = (Element) node;

                System.out.println("test: " + element.getAttribute("src"));
            }

But it does not work.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Do you want any information other than the URLs?  (I don’t know where you got `"src"` from;  those three letters do not appear anywhere in the XML document.)

Comment: @VGR Sorry there's a mistake I'd like to get the src tag like you said.

Comment: I ask again:  what are you really trying to do?  Do you just want a List of Strings representing the enclosure URLs?  Your code seems to be saving titles as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `getAttribute()` on the `Element` object of the `<item>` tag. However you have to select the `<enclosure>` tag first by using the `getElementsByTagName()` as you already did. So you have to use something like:

```
for (...) {
   // ...

   // "element" is the object for the <item> tag
   Element enclosure = (Element)element.getElementsByTagName("enclosure").item(0);
   String url = enclosure.getAttribute("url");
}
```

Comment: Hey, first thanks to your answer. I've tried your example. But it does not work.

Comment: @marvin_fritz This code in combination with your code in your question is working. Keep in mind that you have to use `"url"` and not `"src"`.